# Creating a parallax affect with react-scroll-parallax and image masks

Tags: css, reactjs, scroll, parallax

Here is the desired outcome I'm looking to achieve by scrolling using [react-scroll-parallax](https://react-scroll-parallax.damnthat.tv/docs/intro).

On Mobile browser

[image: Mobile browser Parallax affect]

[View web browser example here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1brd8hNyUB4erR1K_Ro--NyrEKg6_knRN?usp=sharing)

## Description

I want to create a website with the parallax affect shown above. The key elements being a website build in react containing three pages.

While scrolling from Page 1 to Page 2 I want the mobile device mock to start halfway on the screen (as to avoid the other content of page 1), then move to being basically centered.

While scrolling from Page 2 to Page 3, the website and components stick and once again act like a normal website scroll.

Additionally, during the scroll from Page 1 to Page 2, I want the content inside the device mock to scroll as well.

### What I tried

For starters I was able to get nearly the affect I wanted by using a div with it's z-index and absolute position set, and parallax on translateY of `-50, 125`.

```
<div className={"absolute z-10 w-full"}>
    <Parallax translateY={[-50, 125]}></Parallax>
</div>
```

The problem became however when I wanted to place content inside the div. Having another div within the parallax that also had z-index set seemed to mess with the parallax affect.

### Important notes

#### Content inside device mock

One issue I found that was tricky was trying to place the content inside the device mock. I want a parallax both on the device mock itself, and the content within it.

I'm not entirely sure how I should crop the content inside the device mock.
The device mock svg frame and device mock mask can be found here if you want to give it a try
[Device mock svg and mask](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1brd8hNyUB4erR1K_Ro--NyrEKg6_knRN?usp=sharing)

I tried imgs with various z-indexes, masking the div with an svg mask, using image backgrounds. Nothing is quite getting the preferred outcome.

#### Scaling of device mock

I want to make sure this works well on both mobile and browser. With that said I was trying to use margins to scale the device mock but I had a hard time with trying to then correctly get the mask to work for the content within the mock.

I'm not sure if using dedicated width and height sizes would be the ideal way to go, but very open to suggestions! It seems hard to scale the device frame and the mask properly.

#### Parallax of device and parallax of device content

I want the content inside the device mock to be html so that I can change it more than just an image. That being said the most important feature I want is for both the device and the content inside to have a parallax scroll affect.

### Summary

I know this is a bit much for a quick simple stack overflow issue, but I've been trying a lot to get this to work and just can't seem to nail down the little details correctly. I sincerely appreciate all help and suggestions and if there is anything else I can provide please let me know!

Comment: Here's [a starter](https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-booth-oyuel3?file=/src/App.js). Best of luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trickier part of the request was blowing up the `<svg>`, adding new `<path />` and `<clipPath />` for the color swap inside the phone mock.

Eventually I got it working [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-booth-oyuel3?file=/src/ParallaxIPhone.js). The part linking the clipPath transition to the scroll progress looks like this:

```js
const [y, setY] = React.useState(1739);
const onProgressChange = React.useCallback(
  (a) =>
    setY(Math.max(Math.min(1739, 1739 - ((a - 0.24) / 0.0018) * 17), 36)),
  [setY]
);
const { ref } = useParallax({
  translateY: [0, 185],
  onProgressChange
});
```

The `1739` and `36` are max and min values for the translation and they are strictly related to the svg's viewBox. The other values allow tweaking the start, end and speed of animation, with regards to overall scroll progress.

This, together with some CSS, took care of binding the right animations to the correct scroll progress.
Feel free to tweak it some more, especially if you add more markup.

---

The other thing I wanted was a function activated shortly after scrolling, which would snap the scroll to certain positions. Namely, to the `.page` elements.

I used gsap's [ScrollTrigger](https://greensock.com/scrolltrigger/) plugin for the task, for multiple reasons:

- I'm somewhat familiar with it (used it before)
- it's performant, light and non-obtrusive (basically quits when it detects another user scroll)
- listens to all relevant events (touch, mouse pointer, keyboard) without me having to make sense of them, providing a unified interface.
- uses inertia (if you scroll down faster from page 1 it will scroll past page 2, directly to page 3 - other scroll plugins limit you to having to scroll once for each page change)
- works well on mobile devices

There are other libs/plugins out there for the task, you don't have to use `gsap` (although I do think it's awesome). If you end up including it in your project, make sure you comply with their [licensing](https://greensock.com/why-license/) (which is not MIT).

By the way, my first choice for the parallax effect *per-se* would also be `gsap`, as their timelines provide a lot of flexibility and options.
Their most advanced stuff is reserved for subscribers, but even if you limit yourself to the free plugins, you're still getting more than from alternative libs/plugins, IMHO.

See it [working](https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-goldberg-e82nlu?file=/src/App.js).

Comment: Man that's so awesome! It looks soooo good! Thank you so much!

Comment: how would you change the size of the iPhone if you wanted to scale it up? I tried messing with the `1739` value and the svg viewbox `866 1784` but increasing this only maintains the aspect ratio, it doesn't change the actual size. I noticed in styles.css the .imageContainer svg has height 50vh, and that changes size but messes up the parallax. Am I missing something obvious haha?

Comment: That's one of the many reasons I'd use `gsap`. It gives you granular control over details without messing anything else up. I've updated the CSS with something that should work. Play around with the values.